# Using Helm chart nginx-ingress with custom nginx template

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to install the nginx-ingress controller through Helm but I would like to use a custom nginx template. However, I am having trouble understanding how that works. According to the [docs](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress) I can use a parameter called `controller.customTemplate.configMapName`. The description of the parameter is.

> configMap containing a custom nginx template

I created a ConfigMap containing the nginx template as follows

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-template
data:
  nginx.tmpl: nginx.tmpl
```

The `nginx.tmpl` contains the nginx configuration + plus a custom header on every server block. I install the chart as follows:

```
helm install stable/nginx-ingress --namespace kube-system --set controller.customTemplate.configMapName="nginx-template"
```

However, I'm getting the following error when running above command.

```
Error: release listless-ant failed: Deployment.apps "listless-ant-nginx-ingress-controller" is invalid: [spec.template.spec.volumes[0].configMap.items[0].key: Required value, spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].name: Not found: "nginx-template-volume"]
```

My question is, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you add `--dry-run --debug` to your `helm install` command and search the output for `nginx-template`? I expect it to show you what is in your configmap and also you should see entries under `volumes` and `volumeMounts` for the Deployment

Comment: There should be a volumeMount https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/nginx-ingress/templates/controller-deployment.yaml#L153 using the volume https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/nginx-ingress/templates/controller-deployment.yaml#L188 I'd also suggest trying without the quotes in the value in --set

Comment: Thanks! But how do you define that in a ConfigMap? I tried it without the quotes, but unfortunately no difference.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I just meant to use the debug to see what the template evaluates to as you should see sections corresponding to those and one of them is presumably at fault.

Comment: Also worth doing 'kubectl describe cm nginx-template' and trying to check if the content of the configmap is as you'd expect. It's easy to mistakenly put the name of a file in a configmap rather than the contents. Note the size of the cm when you check it.

Answer (score 1):

The default location of nginx configuration template is `/etc/nginx/template/nginx.tmpl` And you will have to configure this as a volume mount.

You can follow the steps mentioned in the official docs in-case if you are using a custom nginx.conf  https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/custom-template/

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to set `controller.customTemplate.configMapKey` to `nginx.tmpl`.